# Entity Framework 5 code first invalid column name?

Tags: entity-framework

I had asked a question  in this post : Entity Framework 5 invalid column name?, But because of big quantity of code, it was difficult to detected the origin of the problem. So, i reproduced the exception in another simple environment hoping somebody helps me to solve this problem:

In this simple app i use a wpf window with 2 buttons, on for closing the window and the other for adding a simulation that

i fill it in the code.

In brief, the message of the exception is " Invalid column name simulation_SimulationID".

Below the code :

Scripts of the two tables (Generated from sql server 2008)

```
USE [dblease]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Echeance]    Script Date: 10/07/2013 14:54:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Echeance](
[EheanceId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[EchNumber] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[date] [date] NOT NULL,
[principal] [float] NULL,
[interet] [float] NULL,
[isLoy1] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[SimulationId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Echeance] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
 (
[EheanceId] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Echeance]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Echeance_simulation]      FOREIGN KEY([SimulationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[simulation] ([SimulationId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Echeance] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Echeance_simulation]
 GO

 ***************************************************************************

 USE [dblease]
 GO

 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[simulation]    Script Date: 10/07/2013 14:56:32 ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO

  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[simulation](
[SimulationId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[baseLocative] [float] NULL,
[txInt] [float] NULL,
[txVr] [float] NULL,
[Autofin] [float] NULL,
[echjour] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[duree] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[echBegin] [date] NOT NULL,
[loy1] [float] NULL,
[loy1_freq] [tinyint] NULL,
[encfin] [float] NULL,
[loyer] [float] NULL,
[txtva] [float] NULL,
[perio] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[ratio] [numeric](9, 3) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_simulation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
( [SimulationId] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

WPF Window

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        simulation s = new simulation();
        s.baseLocative = 18500;
        s.JourEcheance = 25;
        DateTime dd;
        DateTime.TryParse("25/01/2012", out dd);
        s.BeginEch = dd;
        int m = 01;
        int y = 2012;
        s.duree = 36;
        for (byte i=0;i < 36; i++)
        {
            Echeance ech = new Echeance();
            ech.EchNumber = (byte)(i+1);
            ech.DateEcheance = dd;
            ech.MontantPrincipal = 500;
            ech.MontantInteret = 100;
            ech.MontantHT = 600;
            ech.MontantTVA = 600 * 0.18;
            ech.MontantTTC = ech.MontantHT + ech.MontantTVA;
            s.echeancier.Add(ech);
            m++;
            if (m == 13)
            {
                m = 1;
                y = y + 1;
            }

            DateTime.TryParse("25/" + m.ToString() + "/" + y.ToString(),out dd);
        }

        using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            try
            {
                context.Simulations.Add(s);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            catch (DbUpdateException ex1)
            {
                var innerEx = ex1.InnerException;
                 while (innerEx.InnerException != null)
                    innerEx = innerEx.InnerException;
                    MessageBox.Show(innerEx.Message, "DbUpdateException", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            //throw new Exception(innerEx.Message);
            }

            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex3)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var entry in ex3.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var error in entry.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",
                        entry.Entry.Entity,
                        error.PropertyName,
                        error.ErrorMessage
                    ));
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(),"DbEntityValidationException",MessageBoxButton.OK);
            //throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
        }

            }


    }
}
}
```

The Context :

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{



    public DbSet<simulation> Simulations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Echeance> Echeances { get; set; }


    public MyContext(string cnxString)
        : base(cnxString)
    {
        // Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }


    public MyContext()
        : base("name=dbleaseEntities")
    {
        //  Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);

    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        try
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SimulationMapping());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EcheanceMapping());



            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TotalPri);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TotalInt);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TotalHt);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TotalTva);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TotalTtc);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Montant);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Txtint);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Txtvr);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Autofinancement);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.JourEcheance);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.DureeCtr);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.BeginEch);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Loyer);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Periodicite);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.FirstLoyer);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.TxtTva);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.FrequenceLoy1);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.LoyForDuplicate);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Ratio);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Timbre);
            modelBuilder.Entity<simulation>().Ignore(t => t.Encfin);


            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.NumLoy);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.DateEcheance);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.MontantPrincipal);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.MontantInteret);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.MontantHT);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.MontantTVA);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.MontantTTC);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.FirstLoyer);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.Encours);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.Amortfin);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.TauxTVA);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.tva);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.txtva);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.horstaxe);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.ttc);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.amtfin);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Echeance>().Ignore(t => t.encfin);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;

        }

    }


}
```

Entities :

```
//simulation
public partial class simulation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public long SimulationId { get; set; }
    public Double baseLocative { get; set; }
    public Double txInt { get; set; }
    public Double txVr { get; set; }
    public Double Autofin { get; set; }
    public byte echjour { get; set; }
    public Byte duree { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime echBegin { get; set; }
    public Double loy1 { get; set; }
    public Byte loy1_freq { get; set; }
    public Double encfin { get; set; }
    public Double loyer { get; set; }
    public Double txtva { get; set; }
    public Byte perio { get; set; }
    public Double ratio { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Echeance> echeancier { get; set; }
    //public virtual ICollection<Echeance> echeancier { get; set; }

    //Non mappés 

    Double Totpri;
    Double Totint;
    Double Totht;
    Double Tottva;
    Double Totttc;
    Double loyDuplicate;
    Double _timbre;


    //Constructeur sans paramètres
    public simulation()
    {
        baseLocative = 0.000;
        txInt = 0.000;
        txVr = 0.000;
        Autofin = 0.000;
        echjour = 25;
        duree = 36;
        loyer = 0.000;
        loy1 = 0.000;
        loy1_freq = 1;
        perio = 1;
        txtva = 18.000;
        Totpri = 0.000;
        Totint = 0.000;
        Totht = 0.000;
        Tottva = 0.000;
        Totttc = 0.000;
        loyDuplicate = 0.000;
        _timbre = 0.000;

        int y = DateTime.Today.Year;
        int m = DateTime.Today.Month;
        int djour = DateTime.Today.Day;
        int j = 25;

        if (djour > 25)
        {

            m = m + 1;
            if (m > 12)
            {
                m = 1;
                y = y + 1;
            }
        }



        //Date française
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
        DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
        DateTime dd;

        string datestring = j.ToString() + "/" + m.ToString() + "/" + y.ToString();
        DateTime.TryParse(datestring, culture, styles, out dd);
        echBegin = dd;

        echeancier = new List<Echeance>();
    }


    //Constructeur avec  paramètres
    public simulation(Double bl, Double txi, Double txr, Double autofin, Byte jouech, Byte ldur, DateTime ech1, Double loy1mnt, Byte per, Double timbre)
    {
        baseLocative = bl;
        txInt = txi;
        txVr = txr;
        perio = per;
        Autofin = autofin;
        echjour = jouech;
        duree = ldur;
        echBegin = ech1;
        loy1 = loy1mnt;
        loy1_freq = 1;
        encfin = 0.000;
        ratio = 0.000;
        _timbre = timbre;
        echeancier = new List<Echeance>();
    }


    //Propriété base locative
    public Double Montant
    {
        get { return baseLocative; }
        set
        {
            baseLocative = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Montant");
        }

    }

    //Propriété Taux d'intérêts
    public Double Txtint
    {
        get { return txInt; }
        set
        {
            txInt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Txtint");
        }

    }


    //Propriété Taux valeur résiduelle
    public Double Txtvr
    {
        get { return txVr; }
        set
        {
            txVr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Txtvr");
        }

    }


    //Propriété Autofinancement
    public Double Autofinancement
    {
        get { return Autofin; }
        set
        {
            Autofin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Autofinancement");
        }

    }

    //Propriété Jour échéance
    public Byte JourEcheance
    {
        get { return echjour; }
        set
        {
            echjour = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("JourEcheance");
        }

    }

    //Propriété Jour échéance
    public Byte DureeCtr
    {
        get { return duree; }
        set
        {
            duree = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DureeCtr");
        }

    }

    //Propriété Jour échéance
    public DateTime BeginEch
    {
        get { return echBegin; }
        set
        {
            echBegin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BeginEch");
        }

    }

    //Propriété Jour échéance
    public Double Loyer
    {
        get { return loyer; }
        set
        {
            loyer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Loyer");
        }
    }

    //Périodicté
    public Byte Periodicite
    {
        get { return perio; }
        set
        {
            perio = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Periodicite");
        }
    }



    //Premier loyer
    public Double FirstLoyer
    {
        get { return loy1; }
        set
        {
            loy1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstLoyer");
        }
    }

    public Double TxtTva
    {
        get { return txtva; }
        set
        {
            txtva = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TxtTva");
        }
    }


    //Nombre de répétition du premier loyer
    public Byte FrequenceLoy1
    {
        get { return loy1_freq; }
        set
        {
            loy1_freq = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FrequenceLoy1");
        }
    }


    public Double TotalPri
    {
        get { return Totpri; }
        set
        {
            Totpri = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalPri");
        }
    }

    public Double TotalInt
    {
        get { return Totint; }
        set
        {
            Totint = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalInt");
        }
    }

    public Double TotalHt
    {
        get { return Totht; }
        set
        {
            Totht = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalHt");
        }
    }



    public Double TotalTva
    {
        get { return Tottva; }
        set
        {
            Tottva = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalTva");
        }
    }

    public Double TotalTtc
    {
        get { return Totttc; }
        set
        {
            Totttc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalTtc");
        }
    }


    public Double Encfin
    {
        get { return encfin; }
        set
        {
            encfin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Encfin");
        }
    }

    public Double Ratio
    {
        get { return ratio; }
        set
        {
            ratio = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Ratio");
        }
    }


    public Double LoyForDuplicate
    {
        get
        {
            return loyDuplicate;
        }
        set
        {
            loyDuplicate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LoyForDuplicate");
        }
    }


    //public IList<Echeance> ListEcheances
    public IList<Echeance> ListEcheances
    {
        get
        {
            return echeancier;
        }
        set
        {
            echeancier = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ListEcheance");
        }
    }


    public Double Timbre
    {
        get
        {
            return _timbre;
        }
        set
        {
            _timbre = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Timbre");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

//Echeance
public partial class Echeance : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    public long EheanceId { get; set; }
    public byte EchNumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
    public Double principal { get; set; }
    public Double interet { get; set; }
    public byte isLoy1 { get; set; }
    public long SimulationId { get; set; }
    public virtual simulation simulation { get; set; }

    //Attributs non mappés
    public Double tva { get; set; }
    public Double txtva { get; set; }
    public Double horstaxe { get; set; }
    public Double ttc { get; set; }
    public Double amtfin { get; set; }
    public Double encfin { get; set; }

    //Constructeur avec numéro de loyer
    public Echeance(byte nnloy)
    {
        EchNumber = nnloy;
        date = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 25);
        principal = 0.000;
        interet = 0.000;
        horstaxe = 0.000;
        tva = 0.000;
        ttc = 0.000;
        isLoy1 = 0;
        ttc = 0.000;
        amtfin = 0.000;
        encfin = 0.000;
    }



    //Constructeur sans paramètres avec valeurs par défaut
    public Echeance()
    {
        EchNumber = 0;
        date = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 25);
        principal = 0.000;
        interet = 0.000;
        horstaxe = 0.000;
        tva = 0.000;
        ttc = 0.000;
        isLoy1 = 0;
        ttc = 0.000;
        amtfin = 0.000;
        encfin = 0.000;
    }



    //Propriété Numloy : numéro loyer
    public byte NumLoy
    {
        get { return EchNumber; }
        set
        {
            EchNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Numloy");
        }
    }

    public DateTime DateEcheance
    {
        get { return date; }
        set
        {
            date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DateEcheance");
        }

    }

    public Double MontantPrincipal
    {
        get
        {
            return principal;
        }

        set
        {
            principal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MontantPrincipal");
        }
    }


    public Double MontantInteret
    {
        get
        {
            return interet;
        }

        set
        {
            interet = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MontantInteret");
        }
    }

    public Double MontantHT
    {
        get
        {
            return horstaxe;
        }

        set
        {
            horstaxe = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MontantHT");
        }
    }


    public Double MontantTVA
    {
        get
        {
            return tva;
        }

        set
        {
            tva = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MontantTVA");
        }
    }

    public Double MontantTTC
    {
        get
        {
            return ttc;
        }

        set
        {
            ttc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MontantTTC");
        }
    }


    public byte FirstLoyer
    {
        get { return isLoy1; }
        set
        {
            isLoy1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstLoyer");
        }
    }

    public Double Encours
    {
        get { return encfin; }
        set
        {
            encfin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Encours");
        }
    }


    public Double Amortfin
    {
        get { return amtfin; }
        set
        {
            amtfin = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Amortfin");
        }
    }


    public Double TauxTVA
    {
        get { return txtva; }
        set
        {
            txtva = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TauxTVA");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84dc7e64-f9ae-4a5a-93e9-ef8902c98ca6/entity-framework-5-invalid-column-name?forum=adodotnetentityframework)!

The tip is:

Property echeancier is mentionned twice :

1 : For Entity declaration

```
public virtual IList<Echeance> echeancier { get; set; }
```

2 : For wpf databinding in datagrid

```
blic IList<Echeance> ListEcheances
{
    get
    {
        return echeancier;
    }
    set
    {
        echeancier = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ListEcheances");
    }
}
```

if i remove the second declaration, it works fine.